# Extracting the value stored on a heap using a pointer in rust

Tags: pointers, rust

I've a raw pointer to a pinned object stored on the heap as follows.

```rust
let raw_pointer = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Box::pin(some_object))) as jlong;
```

How do I convert this back into a type of `some_object`?

some_object contains a String in its definition. It cannot derive the `Copy` trait.

Comment: Why boxing a `Pin`?

Comment: in order to store it on the heap?

Comment: `Box::pin()` already stores it on the heap.

Comment: got it yeah, can't convert it into a raw pointer using Box::into_raw since Box::pin returns a Pin<Box<T>>.

Comment: So why not just replace `Box::pin()` with `Box::new()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76626752/how-to-reuse-objects-between-a-java-rust-service-via-jni-using-raw-pointer

Comment: apologies for not providing the entire context, posted another question which gives more context on what i'm trying to do.