# how to reuse objects between a java/rust service via JNI using raw pointer

Tags: java, rust, java-native-interface

I've the following scenario. I've a java service that talks to a rust service via JNI.

I'm planning to re-use an object across multiple jni calls. So, I'm planning to create it in the first JNI call on the heap using a Box and return a raw pointer to the same. I intent to store it as a singleton in the java service.

In each call from java service to rust service , I intent to pass along the singleton(pointer) via JNI, and get a reference to the object using the raw pointer in rust and perform business logic.

Is it guranteed that the pointer will always point to the correct object? or do I need to pin it so that it doesn't move?

Comment: JNI doesn't deal in 'raw pointers'. It deals in 'local references', which don't survive the JNI call unless returned to the calling Java method, in which case you can get a reference to the same object back again in another JNI call ... but not necessarily with the same bitwise value of the reference. As long as you don't store `jobject` values statically on the JNI side there is no cause for alarm.

Comment: I don't follow your comment 100%. can you clarify what you mean by not necessarily with the same bitwise value? If i have a java singleton pointing to a specific location on the native heap, then that should always return the same bitwise value, isn't it?

Comment: Nothing 'point[s] to a specific location on the native heap'. JNI can only see values of type `jobject`, which are *not* 'raw pointers'. They are indirections, as described in the JNI Specification. If you do `jobject object = env->NewObject(...)` and then return `object` to Java, it will receive it as an object reference that it can then supply to another JNI call. The `jobject` value received by that 2nd call may or may not be bitwise identical to the first one, but it will still refer to the same object. You need to have a good look at the JNI Specification.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html -> I read this. so, if the registry is deleted then the reference(s) are gone. however, if there is a global reference (i.e., a singleton), then the boxed object should be identical across jni calls.

Comment: Note: all this stuff about local and global references applies to *Java objects*. It has no bearing on your Rust object.

Comment: @py_ios_dev You keep making baseless or meaningless assertions. Global references are not necessarily (references to) singletons. They are just object  references that you can store statically, up to a point. Weak references are better, but better still is not to use either: just return your references and get them back later in another JNI call. If you want a singleton pattern, store the reference on the Java side, not the JNI side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you took great pains in disguising the address of your boxed object as a simple number, the JVM will not do anything special with that.
It is up to you to ensure that that address remains valid, which in this case mostly means not letting the Box be dropped. From what little I know of Rust, that means either calling `Box::into_raw` or `Box::leak`.

Comment: yes, I'm aware of Box::into_raw :) thanks!

Comment: that makes me question, whether I really need a singleton or not in java?

Comment: Probably not. As long as a Java object has the magic number, it can call your JNI code with that number. It is perfectly fine to pass that number to any number of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pin it.

`Pin` is not a language guarantee; it is a library guarantee. It prevents Rust code from moving the value. If you will not move the value in Rust, it will not be moved. It will stay where it is silently and you can definitely rely on that.

Comment: what happens when GC happens in java? does it not move the value(s) around in native memory's heap?

Comment: @py_ios_dev Yes it does but there is only one way that can concern you: see my comment under your question.